# Update Trigger problem

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I have two custom objects: `revenue__c` & `user_revenue__c`. There is a lookup relationship between them. `Revenue__c` is the parent. Now I have a trigger on `revenue__c` that creates some `user_revenue__c` records whenever a `revenue__c` record is inserted or updated. (The number and value of the `user_revenue__c` records created depend on other lookup field, but this is not important for my question).

When I insert a `revenue__c` record, the trigger works fine, but it doesn't work in the update case.

The code:

```
 List < Id > accountIds = new List < Id > ();
 set < Id > revIds = new set < Id > ();
 List < User_Revenue__c > userRevenues = new List < User_Revenue__c > ();

 if (Trigger.isDelete) { //geting all the process IDs
    for (Revenue__c r: Trigger.old) {
        if (r.Account__c != null) accountIds.add(r.Account__c);


        revIds.add(r.ID);

    } else if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        for (Revenue__c r: Trigger.new) {
            if (r.Account__c != null) accountIds.add(r.Account__c);

            revIds.add(r.Id);

        }
    }

    //the following part is working for insert, but if I remove trigger.isinsert and leave trigger.isupdate, it's not working

    if ((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
        if (accountIds != null && accountIds.size() > 0) {

            for (Revenue__c rev: [Select Contract__c, Account__c, Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_1__c, Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_2__c,
            Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_3__c
            from Revenue__c where Account__c in : accountIds and Status__c = 'Received'
            and Id in : revIds]) {

                if (rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_1__c != null) userRevenues.add(createRecord(rev, rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_1__c));
                if (rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_2__c != null) userRevenues.add(createRecord(rev, rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_2__c));
                if (rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_3__c != null) userRevenues.add(createRecord(rev, rev.Account__r.Revenue_Split_Owner_3__c));
            }

        }

        if (userRevenues != null && userRevenues.size() > 0) insert(userRevenues);


    } //END TRIGGER INSERT

    //this code deletes the user revenue records
    if (Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore) {
        userRevenues = new List < User_Revenue__c > ();
        userRevenues = [Select ID from User_Revenue__c where Revenue__c in : revIds];
        system.debug('inside trgr after delete: userRev.size()' + userRevenues.size());

        delete userRevenues;



        User_Revenue__c createRecord(Revenue__c rev, ID user) {
            User_Revenue__c u = new User_Revenue__c(Revenue__c = rev.ID, User__c = user);
            if (rev.Account__c != null) u.Account__c = rev.Account__c;
            else if (rev.Contract__c != null) u.Contract__c = rev.Contract__c;

            return u;
        }

    }
```

I removed some parts of the code since they are not relevant to my problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you configured the trigger to be fired on *update* as well? i.e. like `Trigger myTrigger on revenue__c(after update, after insert) `

Comment: You are using after triggers, right?

Comment: Where are you setting `revIds`?

Comment: Why is the `createRecord` method inside the if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        for (Revenue__c r: Trigger.new) {
            if (r.Account__c != null) accountIds.add(r.Account__c);

            revIds.add(r.Id);

        }
```

You are setting revIds here but not for update condition. So revids are empty in update trigger.  You need to populate revIds for Trigger.isUpdate condition.